# Issue with async code when using WebView2 control inside VSTO Outlook plugin

Tags: c#, async-await, vsto, webview2

I want to use the latest Microsoft WebView2 control (Chromium) on a VSTO plugin for Outlook.
I have the trouble with wiring together async interface of WebView2 with VSTO Outlook.Inspector and Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event, like Send or Close.

I want to execute some JS script on WebView2 on these events by calling ExecuteScriptAsync from WebView2 control.

The trouble is that for instance Send event is declared as
`void ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(ref bool Cancel)`
The problem is with ref variable that it cannot be used for async.

I need to wrap this async code into sync to determine the result for ref Cancel, but I have no idea for it. I'm ending up with deadlock or the error from WebView2 control `CoreWebView2 can only be accessed from the UI thread.`

The setup is VS2019, Outlook PIA 15 and WebView2 1.0.1020.30

Comment: Show more code, so we have something to 'work with' insted of just describing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event handler, run Windows message loop while waiting for the async method to return

```
        MSG msg;
        while (PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 1/*PM_REMOVE*/))
        {

            TranslateMessage(ref msg);
            DispatchMessage(ref msg);
            if (OnlyOnce) break;
        }
```

Win API functions are defined below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MSG
        {
            public IntPtr hwnd;
            public uint message;
            public UIntPtr wParam;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public int time;
            public POINT pt;
            public int lPrivate;
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern sbyte GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref MSG lpMsg);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage([In] ref MSG lpmsg);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool PeekMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax, uint wRemoveMsg);
```

Comment: Thanks for an idea!